# Extends class that has itself as a member

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, binary-tree, nodes

Suppose I have to use a lib that has a class that implements a binary tree, with signature like that:

```
class Node {
    public void setN0(Node n);
    public void setN1(Node n);
    public Node getN0();
    public Node getN1();
}
```

So, I want to create a class that extends this, to put a graphical layer over it, like

```
class UINode extends Node {
    private int coordinateX;
    private int coordinateY;
}
```

But I can't do that because its not possible to pass UInode's to be Node childs, like

```
UINode root = new UINode();
UINode n0 = new UINode();
UINode n1 = new UINode();
root.setN0(n0);  //Not possible
root.setN1(n1);  //Not possible
```

Is there a design pattern or something to deal with this situation? Or there is a simple solution that I cant see?

Comment: It is possible.  If a `UINode` is a `Node`, then you can pass it into any method that takes a `Node`.

Comment: What leads you to believe it's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is possible to set the `UINode` as child of `Node`:

```
UINode root = new UINode();
UINode n0 = new UINode();
root.setN0(n0);  // possible
```

But you have to cast it if you want to get it from the `root` object:

```
UINode n = (UINode) root.getN0();
```

---

Beside that: If you want to implement this yourself - assumed it is **not** in a library - you could create a generic `Node` class:

```
class Node<T extends Node> {
    public void setN0(T n);
    public void setN1(T n);
    public T getN0();
    public T getN1();
}
```

Now you can extend this class in your `UINode`:

```
class UINode extends Node<UINode> {
    // ...
}
```

And use it without casts:

```
UINode root = new UINode();
root.setN0(new UINode());

UINode n = root.getN0();
```